# Создать синоним метки кириллица/cyrillic

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Прошу сделать метку [кириллица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) синонимом для [cyrillic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic).